# Cursor input errors when multithreading with python curses librairy

Tags: python, multithreading, curses

I'm trying to use curses for a class project where we need to use python

The premise is a server/client chat. I was trying to implement it such that the incoming messages from the server would be displayed above the message prompt. I was able to circumvent the python input() function pausing the program with a second thread displaying the messages I decided to use curses to print things at different parts of the screen.

when I tried multi threading with curses I it had a lot of issues with the input cursor. It used displayed the characters that were being input to the program right next to the incoming chat text despite the cursor visually moving back on the screen to the input area

I've isolated the code that's supposed to make this happen:

```
import threading
from time import sleep
import curses

screen = curses.initscr()

screen.clear()
screen.refresh()
num_rows, num_cols = screen.getmaxyx()

#prints what would be chat to the top of the screen
def thread_delay(thread_name, delay):
    i = 0
    while i < 10: 
        #is supposed to save the cursor's location before moving it
        global x_location, y_location
        x_location, y_location = curses.getsyx()
        screen.addstr(0+i, 0, "stuff")
        screen.refresh()
        
        #is supposed to restore the cursor to the input location
        curses.setsyx(x_location, y_location)
        curses.doupdate()
        sleep(1)
        i+=1
#gets and displays input to the bottom of the screen
def my_raw_input(stdscr, r, c, prompt_string):
    curses.echo() 
    
    stdscr.addstr(r, c, prompt_string)
    stdscr.refresh()
    global input
    input = stdscr.getstr(r + 1, c, 20)
    return  #       ^^^^  reading input at next line 


#threads
t1 = threading.Thread(target = thread_delay, args = ('t1', 1,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target = my_raw_input, args = (screen, num_rows - 4, 0, "type what you want"))
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
curses.napms(3000)
curses.endwin()

#for debugging
print(input.decode('utf-8'))
```

Picture of what is happening vs what's supposed to happen:
[image]

Comment: also if anyone knows a way to do this without the curses library let me know, this is just for extra credit so there aren't libraries that I can't use.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your class is over, so it might not be useful anymore...

There are several problems....

first problem is that you are not accepting curses text input, and instead using standard input. The curses module, works by moving the cursor around and adding a character, so wherever your last addstr or addch command ends is where the cursor is positioned, and will next add text. So you could possibly move the cursor back to where you want the input to go, after writing to the screen or you could use curses to capture keyboard input.

Secondly using curses in two processes at the same time is probably not a good idea, since it bypasses the GIL. Instead, you could split your code threads into a server and a curses TUI, and share a global send queue and a receive queue from the **multiprocessing.Manager** to transfer messages.

Then your server thread can send messages from the send_queue with a **.get()** and receive messages and putting them in the receive_queue with a **.put()**. Conversely your curses thread can display messages from the recv_queue with a **.get()** and put a string composed from **curses.getch()** or **curses.getkey()** into the send_queue with a **.put()**

also consider using the curses.wrapper to simplify entering and exiting your curses features. I think you probably didn't use this, because you tried to use curses over multiple processes in which case a wrapper might not work so well.

I'm sure there are other and probably better ways to do it, but this is just one of many. But I hope this helps someone, or encourages someone more experienced to contribute a better answer.